# How to aggregate/list values of multiple columns by group?

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a data frame describing the ownership levels of companies that looks like this:

```
Company   Subsidiary1    Subsidiary2    Subsidiary3
DE5930      DE5931           NA             NA
GB3489      GB3490           NA             NA
GB3489      GB3490         GB3491           NA
US2036      US2037           NA             NA
US2036      US2037         US2038           NA
US2036      US2037         US2038         GB3491
....# and so on
```

Now I would like to create one column of all subsidiaries per company that should look like this:

```
Company   Subsidiaries
DE5930     DE5931          
GB3489     GB3490
GB3489     GB3491
US2036     US2037
US2036     US2038       
US2036     GB3491
```

The dataset is really large (more than 100.000 rows) and I could not figure any solutions using the `group_by` or `aggregate` function as most examples are for numeric variables (e.g. average).

One idea would be to remove the duplicates with `df[ !duplicated(df$Subsidiary1), ]` to retain the first occurence of each subsidiary and then shift the values to the left, but the problem is that one subsidiary could belong to several companies (like "GB3491") and I do not want to loose these observations. Is there any elegant solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest next `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(Company = c("DE5930", "GB3489", "GB3489", "US2036", 
"US2036", "US2036"), Subsidiary1 = c("DE5931", "GB3490", "GB3490", 
"US2037", "US2037", "US2037"), Subsidiary2 = c(NA, NA, "GB3491", 
NA, "US2038", "US2038"), Subsidiary3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"GB3491")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The code:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Company) %>% select(-name) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(paste(Company,value)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Company value 
  <chr>   <chr> 
1 DE5930  DE5931
2 GB3489  GB3490
3 GB3489  GB3491
4 US2036  US2037
5 US2036  US2038
6 US2036  GB3491
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    transmute(Company, Subsidiaries = 
        coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(rev(names(df1)[-1]))))
#  Company Subsidiaries
#1  DE5930       DE5931
#2  GB3489       GB3490
#3  GB3489       GB3491
#4  US2036       US2037
#5  US2036       US2038
#6  US2036       GB3491
```

---

Or with `base R` using `max.col`

```
cbind(df1[1], Subsidiaries =  df1[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 
         max.col(!is.na(df1[-1]), "last"))])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Company = c("DE5930", "GB3489", "GB3489", "US2036", 
"US2036", "US2036"), Subsidiary1 = c("DE5931", "GB3490", "GB3490", 
"US2037", "US2037", "US2037"), Subsidiary2 = c(NA, NA, "GB3491", 
NA, "US2038", "US2038"), Subsidiary3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"GB3491")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```